# parse inputs in a string table

Tags: java

Hi i have this part of code, I want to make a string table with some inputs but i get this error

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:417)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
```

here is my code

```
String[] temp2 = null;
                temp2 = dog1.lineDelimiter(resultdog1[0], 6, "#");  // spaei se 6 strings

                dog1.setId(temp2[0]);
                dog1.Posotita=Integer.parseInt(temp2[1]);
                dog1.Price=Double.parseDouble(temp2[2]);
                dog1.setPerigrafi(temp2[3]);
                dog1.Size=Integer.parseInt(temp2[4]);
                dog1.setRatsa(temp2[5]);


                String lastPelatis=itm.LastInput("Pelates.txt");
                  String[] tempPel = null;
                tempPel = dog1.lineDelimiter(lastPelatis, 6, "#");  // spaei se 6 strings

                pel.setUserName(tempPel[0]);
                    pel.setPassword(tempPel[1]);
                    pel.setAdress(tempPel[2]);
                    pel.setFName(tempPel[3]);
                    pel.setLName(tempPel[4]);
                    pel.setTelephone(tempPel[5]);


                String[] timologio;

timologio = new String[12];
timologio[0] = tempPel[0];
timologio[1] = tempPel[2];
timologio[2] = tempPel[3];
timologio[3] = tempPel[4];
timologio[4] = tempPel[5];
timologio[5]="//";
dog1.setId(timologio[6]);
dog1.Posotita=Integer.parseInt(timologio[7]);
dog1.Price=Double.parseDouble(timologio[8]);
dog1.setPerigrafi(timologio[9]);
dog1.Size=Integer.parseInt(timologio[10]);
dog1.setRatsa(timologio[11]);

timologio[0]=pel.toString();
```

Comment: can you please specify what are you passing to the String[]'s ? Your casts might be incorrect

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse something that is not an integer. Can you look at what are you feeding the `parseInt` function and make sure it really is a number?

Comment: It isn't, because it is `null`. The elements of `timologio` aren't initialized started from index 6.

Comment: it's started from where? how can i make the string i want?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you surround your parseInt and parseDouble statements with a try/catch and catch a NumberFormatException.

For example,

```
try {
  dog1.Posotita=Integer.parseInt(timologio[7]);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  if (null == timologio[7]) System.err.println("timologio[7] is null!");
  else System.err.println("Cannot parse timologio[7] of <" + timologio[7] + ">");
  timologio[7] = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // or other error of your choice
}
```